# How to parse a BPMN file with Java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, bpmn

I don't have much experience with Java nor with BPMN but **m****y goal is to create a code that parse a .bpmn file deducing some information from it**.

I don't need to execute the processes, I just need to infer some informations such as:

- which are the participant;
- what participant executes a specific task;
- which tasks follow a given task;

I've tried to look into the main technologies such as: Camunda, Flowable and jBPM; but to me they all seem to target the execution of processes rather than a merely syntactic analysis (which I think is what I need).

I'm now thinking of creating a code that parse the XML of a BPMN diagram using technologies like DOM or SAX.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I should approach my goal ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the Camunda library I used here:
https://github.com/rob2universe/bpmn-creator

Alternatively, if you prefer JS, you may find https://bpmn.io/ helpful.

Comment: Hi, first of all I want to thank you for the answer: the CAMUNDA Model Builder API  was exactly what I was looking for. Since I am a complete beginner I have another question: I saw that to use the aforementioned API you need to create an Eclipse Maven project with a specific POM.xml file; is there a way to use the API just in a normal project ??

Comment: This is not an exclipse project, just a Maven project. Maven woudl be the defacto standard to manage the required dependency in Java project, but you don't have to use maven. You can also just add the jars whcih Maven loads in a differnet way to your classpath. If the answer helped, then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

BPMN files usually are structured as XML. So you can do your own XML-Parsing using [JAXP](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jaxp-introduction.html). I also use the SAXparser, find a little introduction [here](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/).

I read there are BPMN libraries for Java, too, but I haven't tried any of these jet. Here is a good stack link for this topic: [Parsing BPMN file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711819/parsing-bpmn-file)

Hope this helps for a start :)